# How to access Keras variables in callback or elsewhere by name since Keras variable names do not appear in summaries?

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

This is in tensorflow-2.0 keras.

```
x_input keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
V = K.variable(0.5, name='V', dtype=tf.float32)
V = tf.reduce_mean(x_input, axis=-1) * 0 + V # this is a stupid way to get things to work
V = tf.expand_dims(V, axis=-1)

model = keras.models.Model(inputs=x_input, outputs=V)
```

I then use this model (uncompile) as an input into another model construction procedure.

The variabel "V" does not show up in the summary of either the first of second model. How to get a hold of the value V in callbacks or even in eager mode?

Comment: what if give it a unique name and not reuse V. would that work for you ?

Comment: Yeah, that is basically what I ended up trying. Am now just using the keras subclassing API. I think that is where everyone should be anyway: always use the subclassing API until things get sorted with keras.

Comment: I agree with using the subclassing API